# How do I implement a background-color into my HTML program?

Tags: html, url

I am currently taking a coding course and I am learning how to code in Python (Python 3) and I am doing an assignment that involves making my own webpage. In the instructions of the assignment, it says I have to implement either a background color or a background image and I found some code that did exactly that but when I run it through the course's grader, it says I am missing that. I am currently coding on Repl.it. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Is there another way that I can implement a background color?

**Here are the assignment instructions:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>All About Sharks</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#86A2FF"> 

<h1 align = "center" style ="color:White;font-family:Times;font-size:50px">All About Sharks</h1>

<a href="https://seethewild.org/shark-threats/">Endangered Sharks Page</a>
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">Send Mail Here</a>
<hr>


<h2 style ="color:White;font-size:20px;font-family:Arial"> What Are Sharks?</h2>

<p style ="color:Black;font-family:Times"><b><i> Sharks are a type of long-bodied marine fish with a cartilaginous skeleton (skeleton made entirely of cartilage), a large dorsal fin, and toothlike scales (also called placoid). Most sharks are predatory, although the largest kinds feed on plankton, and some can grow to larger sizes.</b></i></p>

<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e3c/shark-1367473.jpg" width="250" height="200">
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/42c/shark-1384982.jpg" width="250" height="200" class="center">

<hr>

<h3 style ="color:White;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px"> Where Are Sharks Found?</h3>

 <p style ="color:Black;font-family:Times"><b><i>Sharks are found in all five of the Earth's oceans: the Atlantic, Pacific, Indian, Arctic, and Southern. Although they are commonly found in oceans, sharks can also be found in freshawater lakes and some rivers.</b></i></p>
 
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/749/flatnose-shark-1250133.jpg" width="250" height="200">
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/201/shark-1520496.jpg" width="250" height="200" class="center">

<hr>

<h4 style ="color:White;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px"> What Do Sharks Eat?</h4>

<p style ="color:Black;font-family:Times"><b><i>Sharks eat a wide variety of marine life ranging from smaller organisms like snails, sea urchins, crabs, and fish to larger organisms like stingrays, other sharks, seals, and birds.

<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/cd1/blue-crab-1539361.jpg" width="250" height="200">
<img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/50f/stingray-1520490.jpg" width="250" height="200" class="center">

<hr>

<h5 style ="color:White;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px"> What Is The Purpose Of This Page?</h5>

<p style ="color:Black;font-family:Times"><b><i>The entire purpose of this page is to bring attention to educate about endangered marine animals, particularly sharks. According to IUCN analysts, among all 470 species of sharks, 2.4 percent are critically endangered, 3.2 percent are endangered, 10.3 percent are vulnerable, and 14.4 percent are near threatened. Sharks are considered apex predators (meaning that they sit at the very top of the food chain) and their lives are being threatened everyday by commercial shark finning (usually for medicine or shark fin soup), overfishing, fisheries bycatch, and habitat and prey loss.

<hr>


</body>
</html>
```

**The line that says

```html
<body bgcolor="#86A2FF">
```

is my background color code.**

**NOTE: My pictures may look a little weird under the header What Do Sharks Eat.**

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using CSS inline styles:

```
<body style="background-color: red">
...
</body>
```

The reason why your course grader doesn't think that this method is correct is probably because it's rather unconventional to use the *bgcolor* property.